# Foundation 5 Top Bar full width, but inside elements contained to grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm working with Foundation 5's top bar and I'd like the bar to be full width, but the actual navigation links to be contained to the grid. I want the navigation items to align with the body of text.

I've tried adding a row and/or columns inside the nav. I've tried using `.contain-to-grid` inside the nav and nothing seems to be working.

Here is my codepen to see: http://codepen.io/eladrin201/pen/BNGroR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the nav outside with `.contain-to-grid` and not inside.

```
<div class="contain-to-grid"> <!-- Wrap -->
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"></li>
    <!-- Rest of code -->
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

**Default CSS**

```
.contain-to-grid .top-bar { /* Targets the descendant/child element */
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 62.5rem;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/ManojAMK/pen/gpQeoR)

Comment: Perfect. For whatever reason I thought this was going to contain the entire bar not just the nav items. Thanks for your help.